# Where does the error come from? Valgrind / C / insertString

Tags: c, unit-testing, valgrind

for one of my project i have to make a new version of the function insertString,you could see the code below:

This function always gives me the desired result, (I made some Unit test), however the main issue is this one: even if it works in my IDE (compilation etc) it won't pass unit test using Valgrind, is there anyone who could see the error?

```
char * insertString(const char * src, int insertPosition, const char * toBeInserted,int insertLength)
{
    size_t outputSize=stringLength(src)+(size_t)insertLength;
    char* output=malloc(sizeof(char)*(outputSize+1));
    int i;

    if(output==NULL)
    {
        fatalError("error during memory allocation in InsertString");
    }

    for(i=0;i<insertPosition;i++)
    {
        output[i]=src[i];
    }
    for(i=0;i<insertLength;i++)
    {
        output[i+insertPosition]=toBeInserted[i];
    }
    for(i=0;i<=insertLength;i++)
    {
        output[i+insertPosition+insertLength]=src[insertPosition+i];
    }

    output[outputSize]='\0';
    return output;

}
```

thank's for everything, and have a good Sunday!

Comment: *What* error do you get?

Comment: And are you sure that e.g `i+insertPosition+insertLength` is smaller than `outputSize`? Or that `insertPosition+i` is less than the size of `src`?

Comment: Also, the loop condition in the last loop looks suspect.

Comment: thank's for the answer, i+insertPosition+insertLength is smaller.
I made few change on the last loop, and i think that the problem come from there!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The terminating condition, `i<=insertLength`, in your last loop:

```
for(i=0;i<=insertLength;i++)
{
    output[i+insertPosition+insertLength]=src[insertPosition+i];
}
```

has nothing to do with the length remaining in `src`. If `insertLength` is large enough, the code will read past the end of `src`.

Change it to something like (I think):

```
for(i=0;i<=strlen(src)-insertPosition;i++)
{
    output[i+insertPosition+insertLength]=src[insertPosition+i];
}
```

Also, in my opinion the code could be made much more easily understood (and therefore verifiable) by using a running index for the `output` buffer instead of resetting it to `0` for each loop and adding other values for the subscript. Alternatively, I think using pointers to traverse the various buffers would be more readable:

```
char* tmp = output;

for(i=0;i<insertPosition;i++)
{
    *tmp++ = *src++;
}
for(i=0;i<insertLength;i++)
{
    *tmp++ = *toBeInserted++;
}
for(i=insertPosition;i<=strlen(src);i++)
{
    *tmp++ = *src++;
}

*tmp++ = '\0';
```

Comment: I tried and it works, i don't even know why i put this condition there... However i spent something like 1 hour without finding it... Thank's :)